# Can I save the already downloaded blocks to another file location am almost out of space on my drive

Tags: block

Can I save the already downloaded blockchains to another file location am almost out of space on my drive and i have not completed the network synchronization

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you can move the files to another folder and specify it to bitcoind/bitcoin-qt when launching it with the [-datadir parameter](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin):

> -datadir=  Specify data directory

As an alternative, you can also specify the data directory in the [Bitcoin.conf file](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File), so that you don't have to include the parameter every time you lauch the daemon.